# Xcode 4.4 : Preferences : Downloads : Components : Command Line Tools fails with "Failed with HTTP status 403: forbidden"

Tags: installation, command-line-tool, xcode4.4

does anyone know what i might have to change (permissions on a particular file; clearing out a Keychain Access item) to resolve an issue when i attempt to install command line tools inside of my freshly download Xcode 4.4 install?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on a whim, this morning, i tried again, and now it works.

it presents me with a dialog asking me for my master keychain password, and then starts downloading the command line tools.

anyone following this may wish to try again themselves.  hopefully the problem is resolved for all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. My guess is that it's related to the fact that it's only *just* been released. It's not even present on the developer website yet.

[edit]
It appears to be working as expected now.

Comment: Same problem here, with both my ancient ADC account and a new one I made to demonstrate the issue to Apple Support when they tried to mark it "can't reproduce."

Answer (score 0):

registering as a developer allows you to download the command line tools

Comment: Worked for me. Here's an actual link since mike couldn't be bothered: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action

Comment: for now, i'm going with @NeilTraft's link so i can get going.  i'd still like to know if/when/what apple is going to do about this.  i saw a couple of people having the same problem when i checked apple dev forums, but no response from apple.  anyone else using neil's link … be careful to get the right DMG for your OS … 10.7 or 10.8 .